# Direct Limit of Power Series

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Consider the following directed system of power series
$$R[[X_1]]\hookrightarrow R[[X_1,X_2]]\hookrightarrow\cdots\hookrightarrow\varinjlim_iR[[X_1,\ldots, X_i]]=\bigcup_i R[[X_1,\ldots, X_i]] $$
**Question 1** Is $R[[X_1,X_2,\ldots]]=\bigcup_i R[[X_1,\ldots, X_i]]$? This is true for polynomial rings.
**Question 2** If above not true, how can we express $R[[X_1,X_2,\ldots]]$ as a direct limit of Notherian rings?
Edit: Let $f=X_1+X_2+\ldots+X_k+\ldots$, then $f\in R[[X_1,X_2,\ldots]]$, but $f\notin R[[X_1,\ldots, X_i]]$ for any $i$, thus $f\notin\bigcup_i R[[X_1,\ldots, X_i]] $. The universal property of direct limit now gives $\bigcup_i R[[X_1,\ldots, X_i]] \subsetneq R[[X_1,X_2,\ldots]]$. The example given by @logarithm can also be used. But, **Question 2** is still open.

Comment: Look at $\sum_nX_n^n$.

Comment: Or $\sum_n X_n$ which does not lie in any $R[[X_1,\ldots X_i]]$ and hence does not lie in the union. But, how to address **Question 2**?

Comment: How are you defining $R[[X_1,X_2,...]]$? the completion of $R[X_1,X_2,...]$ with respect to the ideal $(X_1,X_2,...)$, or as functions from $\mathbb{N}^{\oplus\mathbb{N}}$ to $R$? In the first case $\sum_nX_n$ doesn't belong to it. I took $\sum_nX_n^n$ as it would belong choice of definition.

Comment: For (2) you can look at the finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-subalgebras of it. Take the arrows to be their inclusions when one of them is included in another.

Comment: Thank You @logarithm , I was thinking completion. Is there a concrete example for **Question 2**?

Comment: If it is the completion, then you need to use $\sum_nX_n^n$, since $\sum_nX_n$ doesn't belong to the completion. I don't know if there is some easy way to express it as a limit of Noetherians. It doesn't look like it will be the union of countably many of them.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense.

Comment: Any ring is a direct limit of noetherian rings as it is the direct limit of its finitely generated subrings, and any finitely generated ring is noetherian

Comment: @Max Thanks!!, I know this, but is there a concrete direct limit for $R[[X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_k,\ldots]]$ consisting only of Notherian rings. In fact the question(s) arose because of the search for directed system of Noetherian rings which lead to the example.