# Commutativity of Direct and Inverse Limits for Tate Algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

This question is a continuation of 
([Commutativity of Direct and Inverse Limits for a special case.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3225765/673630)) and ([Direct Limit of Power Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3224458/673630))

Let $A_i=\mathbb{Z}_p\langle X_1,\ldots X_i \rangle$ Tate algebra obtained from $p$ adic completion of $\mathbb{Z}_p[X_1,\ldots, X_n]$ and thus (by assumption) $\varprojlim_\lambda A_i=A_i$, where $\varprojlim_\lambda$ is $p$ adic completion. Consider the following directed system 
$$
\begin{equation}\label{one}
A_1\hookrightarrow A_2\hookrightarrow \ldots\hookrightarrow A_i\hookrightarrow\ldots\hookrightarrow \varinjlim_i A_i=\bigcup_i A_i
\end{equation}
$$

Apply inverse limit to the above and since by assumption $\varprojlim A_i=A_i$ this gives
$$
A_1\hookrightarrow A_2\hookrightarrow \ldots\hookrightarrow A_i\hookrightarrow\ldots\hookrightarrow \varprojlim_\lambda\varinjlim_i A_i
$$

The universal property of direct limit gives the map $\varinjlim_i A_i\rightarrow\varprojlim_\lambda\varinjlim_i A_i$ and universal property of inverse limit gives the map $\varprojlim_\lambda\varinjlim_i A_i\rightarrow\varinjlim_i A_i $.

**Question 1** Can we conclude that in the above case $\varinjlim_i A_i=\varprojlim_\lambda\varinjlim_i A_i$? Why?
**Question 2** If above not true, is $\varprojlim_\lambda\varinjlim_i A_i=\mathbb{Z}_p\langle X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_i,\ldots \rangle$, it is known that $\varinjlim_iA_i=\bigcup_i\mathbb{Z}_p\langle X_1,\ldots, X_i\rangle$.

Comment: I think the answer is again no : take $\displaystyle\sum_n p^n X_n$ which is in the completion of $\varinjlim_i \mathbb{Z}_p\langle X_1,...,X_n\rangle$; but not in any of the $\mathbb{Z}_p\langle X_1,...,X_n\rangle$

Comment: Thanks! I assume that the comment in **Question 2** holds.

Comment: By $\mathbb{Z}_p\langle X_1,...\rangle$ do you mean the completion of $\mathbb{Z}_p[X_1,...]$ ?

Comment: If yes, the for question 2, the RHS is $\varprojlim_n (\varinjlim_i A_i)/p^n$ which is $\varprojlim_n \varinjlim_i A_i/p^n$ so $\varprojlim_n \varinjlim_i \mathbb{Z/p^nZ}[X_1,...,X_i]$ so $\varprojlim_n \mathbb{Z/p^nZ}[X_1,...]$ and so $\varprojlim_n \mathbb{Z}_p[X_1,...]/p^n$ and therefore $\mathbb{Z}_p\langle X_1,...\rangle$, which is the LHS